# finding index of element

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="TopClass">

  <div class="ContentClass">
    <div class="ActionClass">action</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="ContentClass">
    <div class="ActionClass">action</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="ContentClass">
    <div class="ActionClass">action</div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

I'm looking to get the index of the action class relative to TopClass; if the user clicks on the second Action class, it should return 2.

```
$('.ActionClass').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().index());  // not working    
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)  like this which will always give you the index of `.ActionClass` even if the structure changes. But as `.index` returns `0-based` index I am adding `1` into it's output:

```
$('.ActionClass').click(function () {
   alert($(this).closest('.TopClass').find('.ActionClass').index(this) + 1);
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/g5mVx/3/)

Another shorter way can be like this, it works fine with only one parent `.TopClass` container so far but use carefully if you have a different structure. Previous one is safer and works for general cases

```
$('.ActionClass').click(function () {
   alert($('.ActionClass').index(this) + 1);
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/g5mVx/6/)

Comment: ok, thanks; works like I need it. The HTML actually has classes in between so your solution takes that into consideration. See here: jsfiddle.net/AhReg/2

Comment: Another shorter way can be http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/g5mVx/5/ , not sure if it will work in all cases. But seems it will.

Comment: @Joy: `this` is an `.ActionClass` so you could also just do `$('.ActionClass').index(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct, just get index from parent node:

```
$('.ActionClass').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().index());
});
```

​**Disclaimer**

This doesn't work when there are other siblings besides `.ContentClass`. For that you should refer to Joy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879295/1338292).

Comment: This doesn't work. If you add classes between, the number is off. Check here jsfiddle.net/AhReg/2

Comment: I somewhat agree but I did specify for the index of the element and the solution of Joy works like I need it. I understand your logic thought because that's where I was stuck with the .parent() function and that wasn't working. Upvoted for effort; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent().parent() is taking you too high in the structure:

```
$('.ActionClass').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().index());  // not working    
});​
```

Will work, but its zero based so you'll get 0, 1 and 2 for the three div clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/amelvin/AhReg/

**EDIT**

Based on you amendment you can use the optional selector variable on the index() method.

```
<div class="TopClass">

  <div class="ContentClass">
    <div class="ActionClass">action</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="ContentClass">
    <div class="ActionClass">action</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>  
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>  
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>  

  <div class="ContentClass">
    <div class="ActionClass">action</div>
  </div> 

</div>​

$('.ActionClass').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().index(".ContentClass"));  // not working    
});​
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you add classes between, the number is off. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/AhReg/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = jQuery.inArray($(this)[0], $('.ActionClass')) + 1
```

This solution will work regardless of the HTML structure.  It finds the array index of the clicked '.ActionClass' element in the array containing all matched '.ActionClass' elements.